# Creating an invoice using API

Tags: api, soap, ce-1.9.0.1, vb.net

I am trying to create an invoice via API. I am using Soap V2 and VB.net. I am have trouble creating an array of OrderItmeIdQty. I keep getting a Null Reference Exception was Unhanded. I do not understand how to create the array. Below is my code so far.

```
 Dim mage As New MagentoSOAPV2.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient

 Dim sessionId = mage.login("xxxx", "xxxxxx")

 Dim order = mage.salesOrderInfo(sessionId, "100000020")

 Dim qty(0) As orderItemIdQty

 For Each item As salesOrderItemEntity In order.items

      qty(0).order_item_id = item.order_id
      qty(0).qty = item.qty_ordered

 Next

 Dim invoice As String = mage.salesOrderInvoiceCreate(sessionId, "100000020", qty, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Here is the sample code that magento provides.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

//Create invoice for order
$qty = array(array('order_item_id' => '15', 'qty' => '1'));
$invoiceIncrementId = $proxy->salesOrderInvoiceCreate($sessionID,'200000008',$qty);
var_dump($invoiceIncrementId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my code to work. I was creating an array of objects correctly. Below is the working code.

```
Dim order = mage.salesOrderInfo(sessionId, "100000023")
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim qty(order.items.Length) As orderItemIdQty

For Each item As salesOrderItemEntity In order.items
    qty(count) = New orderItemIdQty
    qty(count).order_item_id = item.item_id
    qty(count).qty = item.qty_ordered
    count = count + 1
Next

Dim invoice As String = mage.salesOrderInvoiceCreate(sessionId, "100000023", qty, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

steve

array should like this

```
$items = array();
     foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $items[$item->getId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        }
```

**Example** an  order have `two Order items`
in **sales_flat_order_item** table

```
OrderItemId OrderQty
15           6
16           2
```

then array should be

```
$arr=array('15'=>6,'16'=>2);
```

check here http://www.amitbera.com/programmatically-create-invoice-of-a-new-order-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I wanted to do this in VB.net. I figured it out though!

Comment: sorry ,dude  i am not a VB developer